# how do I assign the output of plink to a variable in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do I assign the output of the below command which comes out to be like 
      */export/home/xyz*

```
var=(plink -pw "mukesh" "mukesh@192.168.79.128" echo $HOME)
```

and use it here like

```
pscp "C:\Documents and Settings\mukesh\putty\pub.ppk" "mukesh@192.168.79.128:$var/.ssh/puttykey.ppk"
```

I tried this but it did not work.

```
for /f %%i in ('plink -pw "mukesh" "mukesh@192.168.79.128" echo $HOME') do set VAR=%%i
%%i was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: In a batch file you have to use `%%i`. Directly from the command line it should be just `%i`. Perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: thanks @Jon, thats the prob